# how does a python program tell if it's being run within emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

I usually write python in emacs.

I'll often want to re-evaluate my file, which I can do with Ctrl-C Ctrl-C, which causes the interpreter to reload the entire file and then I can carry on playing.

so if I'm writing a program that takes input, I'll usually find myself with two lines:

```
lines = open("/home/jla/inputfile").readlines()
#lines = fileinput.input()
```

the first line is 'what to do while developing' (read from a known example input file)
the second is 'what to do when run from the command line' (read from stdin, or a provided file name)

Obviously this is bad, so I am thinking:

```
if in_emacs():
     lines = open("/home/jla/inputfile").readlines()
if run_from_shell():
     lines = fileinput.input()
else:
     oops()
```

And I know how to write `oops()`, but I am a bit stuck with `in_emacs()` and `run_from_shell()`, and I wonder if you wise ones can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shells opened by emacs should have the environment variable `EMACS=t`. At least this works on my emacs, YMMV.

If that doesn't fly for you, here's how to find out what emacs-dependent environment variables python can see. Run from the shell and under emacs, and compare the outputs.

```
import os
for e in os.environ:
    if 'EMACS' in e:
        print e, os.environ[e]
```

Comment: And just like that, something that has been slightly annoying me for many years in many languages is gone for good. So simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't work for me when using `M-x shell-command`, though: just try `M-!`, then enter the command `python -c "import os; print [k for k in os.environ.keys() if k.startswith('EMACS')]"`. The result for me is `['EMACSPATH', 'EMACSLOADPATH', 'EMACSDOC', 'EMACSDATA']`. The variable `EMACSPATH` (as mentioned in my answer) is set in both shells and one-off commands, and may therefore be a better indicator than `EMACS`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to check for the presence of environment variables like `EMACSPATH` or `EMACSLOADPATH`. Also, depending on how you're starting Python inside Emacs, the value of the `TERM` environment variable may give you a useful clue.